# Is it possible to install Page Builder in a previous version of Magento Commerce ( < 2.3)?

Tags: magento2.2, page-builder

We'd like to know if it's possible to integrate the page builder extension (build in Magento Commerce 2.3) to a 2.2.5.

Did someone already try it, and faced a challenge ?

Is it worth it if the upgrade to 2.3 is planned > 7 months ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page Builder is only supported on Magento Commerce 2.3.1+, you'll need to upgrade to a newer version to get the functionality.

Comment: forgot to update: that not on that project anymore, and I concur, it seemed after some digging that it's very hard without an upgrade ... Thanks